# Poner contenteditable a todos los TD excepto a los ultimos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo una tabla de 5 columnas, con información, la última columna es de acciones (Editar, eliminar, etc). Estoy intentando que al dar click en una icono de editar me habilite la edición de texto de todos los TD del mismo row a excepción del último, pues es una celda de tools, sin embargo no lo consigo. He intentando

```
 !$(this).is('td:last');
 $(this).not('td:last');
 !$(this).is(':last');
 $(this).not(':last');
```

No lo he conseguido, qué puede estar saliendo mal? Este es el código.

```
$(document).on('click','.tool',function(){
  var action     = $(this).data('action'),
      row        = $(this).parents('tr'),
      row_cloned = $(this).clone(),
      id         = parseInt(row.data('id'));
  switch ( action ) {
    case 'edit':
      row.find('td').each(function(){
        if( !$(this).is('td:last') ){
            $(this).prop('contenteditable',true);
        }
      });
      row.find('td:first').focus();
    break;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estabas muy cerca de lo que quieres.  Solo tienes que cambiar tu selector a `$(this).is(':last-child')` asi:

```js
$(document).on('click','.tool',function(){
  var action     = $(this).data('action'),
      row        = $(this).parents('tr'),
      row_cloned = $(this).clone(),
      id         = parseInt(row.data('id'));
  switch ( action ) {
    case 'edit':
      row.find('td').each(function(){
        if( !$(this).is(':last-child') ){
            $(this).prop('contenteditable',true);
        }
      });
      row.find('td:first').focus();
    break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
<td>Test 1</td>
<td>Test 1</td>
<td>Test 1</td>
<td>Test 1</td>
<td><button data-action="edit" class="tool">Editar</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Test 2</td>
<td>Test 2</td>
<td>Test 2</td>
<td>Test 2</td>
<td><button data-action="edit" class="tool">Editar</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Eso ya lo intenté alan, de hecho tu código tampoco funciona, pude editar el botón justo en dandole click en uno de sus bordes sin enviar el trigger del botón.

Comment: Perdon, ya edite, es `last-child`